# Are there any shields that are off-limits to any classes?

Tags: diablo-iii

For some character classes, it is sometimes a good strategy to hold a shield in the off hand.  Are there any shields that are off-limits to any particular classes?  Or are all classes able to wield all shields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All shields can be used by all classes.  There are a number of other off-hand items that are class-specific (Mojos, Orbs, and Quivers).  These do not provide blocking like a shield, and instead generally provide damage bonuses and other attribute bonuses.

Answer (score 0):

While shields are not restricted to a class a shield can have attributes that only benefit a single class (and are marked as such). You are still able to equip them with any class but can't use the full potential of all attributes on that shield.